# Google Web Engine Api Channel vs Node.js+Socket.io

Tags: html, performance, google-app-engine, websocket, socket.io

Please, help me to choose which one to use for my university project (I want to develop a shared multiuser whiteboard).

In particular, I am interested in the performance of message exchange between users and server using [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) and [Socket.io](http://socket.io/): which one is quicker and why?

I have implemented an initial version of the whiteboard http://jvyrushelloworld.appspot.com/ by following this tutorial: http://blog.greweb.fr/2012/03/30-minutes-to-make-a-multi-user-real-time-paint-with-play-2-framework-canvas-and-websocket/  The code I used is pretty much the same, except for the side and message exchange method: I used python, Google Channel API for message exchange; the guy who wrote the tutorial used Play 2 framework and Web sockets.

As you see, the web socket tutorial version works much faster (don't know if it is my mistake or google api channel performance issue). Of course, a lot of optimization can be done to improve the performance, but I wonder if it is worth to go on using Channel API for that project or is it better to switch to socket.io?

Comment: So, I have rewritten the code using node.js and socket.io and free amazon micro instance as a hosting. It works much-much faster now.

Comment: Interesting, can you provide some numbers to explain how much faster it actually is? Are you planning on writing a blog article about it or publish parts of the source otherwise? The big thing that you don't get with an EC2 instance is _automatic scaling_. You would either have to use a static EC2 cluster that is _big enough_ or use [autoscaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/). On GAE you would get the automatic scaling for free.

Comment: So, here is the video on youtube demonstrating the difference http://youtu.be/sI1hb-ybb5w Also, I've written a short article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571333/Google-Web-Engine-Api-Channel-vs-Node-jsplusSocket-io (at the time I was writing this message it hasn't yet been approved by moderator, but it should be pretty soon). The source code is attached to this article.

Comment: Thanks for posting the article and video! But only a repeatable automated test for both implementations would proof the performance difference. With the current setup it is difficult to tell where the bottlenecks are. E.g. maybe the server/network part of the Channel API solution is actually quicker but it feels slower because of all the client side processing. Maybe the way you build the app works for Socket.IO but not for the Channel API. I would love to hear a follow-up on this since there is a high demand for scalable, cheap, low-latency, cross platform messaging architectures.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's probably difficult to tell something based on one video. Here's a nice article about Channel API's performance http://codevizier.blogspot.cz/2012/05/channel-api.html, and here is an interesting app which I've found on the web for testing the performance http://channelapistresstest.appspot.com/ (which is probably more suitable for that purpose than my application)

Comment: @Ievgen Is it possible for you to provide another link to your socket.io/Google channel source code as the link seems to be broken? I'm mainly interested in how you implemented the transition layer between the two.

Comment: @Tamer, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/571333/Google-Web-Engine-API-Channel-vs-Node-jsplusSocket This is the same link as written above, it works fine for me, the source code is attached to the article

Comment: @levgen For some strange reason I keep getting redirected to http://www.codeproject.com/script/Common/Error.aspx?errres=FileNotFound I have tried with both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Tamer, unfortunately, I don't know what the problem is... I have tried it once more in Chrome and Firefox and it works for me(I am not logged in to the website).

Comment: @Tamer, if you would like to, I could send you the source code to your email

Comment: @levgen Very strange, and yes I would like to get a copy via email; however, it might be easier to use dropbox (or similar) instead of exchanging emails publicly.